# 'error ";" expected' when initialising multiple structs

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, c89, hi-tech-c

I have typdef'd a struct, and immediately below this I've simultaneously declared and initialised the variables I want using the typedef'd struct.

When I try to compile the code, there are no error messages relating to 'hi_aud', but the rest of the structs bring up the error 'error: ";" expected'. The array also brings up this warning, plus 'error: "}" expected'.

I'm using Hi-Tech C compiler v., which uses the C90 ANSI C standard.

```
/* Due to C90, do not change order of vars in struct or else code will explode
 */
typedef struct alarm {
    const uint_fast32_t pattern[];
    const uint_fast8_t size;
    void (*toggle)(void);
    void (*off)(void);
    bool on;
    bool init;
    uint_fast8_t pos;
    uint_fast16_t start;
    uint_fast8_t overflows;
};

static struct alarm hi_aud {
    [108, 27, 108, 20, 108, 12, 108, 5],
    sizeof(hi_aud.pattern) / sizeof(*hi_aud.pattern),
    &sounder_toggle,
    &sounder_off,
};

static struct alarm med_aud {
    [255, 50, 50, 255],
    sizeof(med_aud.pattern) / sizeof(*med_aud.pattern),
    &sounder_toggle,
    &sounder_off,
};

static struct alarm lo_aud {
    [255],
    sizeof(lo_aud.pattern) / sizeof(*lo_aud.pattern),
    &sounder_toggle,
    &sounder_off,
};

static struct alarm hi_vis {
    [255],
    sizeof(hi_vis.pattern) / sizeof(*hi_vis.pattern),
    &hi_vis_toggle,
    &hi_vis_off;
};

static struct alarm med_vis {
    [255],
    sizeof(med_vis.pattern) / sizeof(*med_vis.pattern),
    &med_vis_toggle,
    &med_vis_off,
};

static struct *alarms = {&hi_aud, &med_aud, &lo_aud, &hi_vis, &lo_vis};
static uint_fast8_t alarms_siz = sizeof(alarms) / sizeof(*alarms);
```

*edit* When I use the '{}' brackets to initialise the array, another error "error: no identifier in declaration" comes up. This does not happen when I use the '[]' brackets.

Comment: You missed a name for your `typedef struct alarm`.

Comment: Is this `[255, 50, 50, 255]` syntax even legal? Not in ANSI C, AFAIK..

Comment: Looks like you really need to get back to the books.

Comment: There's a typo after `&hi_vis_off` - should be a comma not a semicolon

Comment: @abelenky, there are plenty of problems with the OP's code, including with array initializers, but the most fundamental one seems to be a misunderstanding of the meaning and use of `typedef` vs. structure declarations.  As such, I don't think the chosen dupe target is a good fit.

Comment: Feel free to disagree.   I thought I was simply "voting" to mark it, I did not realize I now have the power to close questions single-handedly!

Comment: @abelenky: With great power also come great responsability :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Inside a strcut's defintion the elements' defintions are separated by `;` not be `,`.</strike> <sup>not the issue :}</sup>

- <strike>Prior to C99 the initialiser list may not end by `,`.</strike><sup>confused by C99 change for enums.</sup> Ending it with a `;` is always wrong. And there needs to be a `=` between the variable and its initialiser.
- To initialise a struct's array member use curly braces (`{}`), not brackets (`[]`).
- `const uint_fast32_t pattern[];` is not a complete array definition.

  Use `const uint_fast32_t pattern[MAX_SOMETHING];` instead.

Comment: This isn't correct, C _always_ allowed initializer lists to end with `,`. From the ANSI C draft: `{  initializer-list }` `{  initializer-list , }`. You are confusing this with trailing comma in enums, which wasn't allowed before C99. The reason it was added was to make enums consistent with arrays.

Comment: The problem is that I forgot to add the '=' between the variable and initialiser. Thanks!

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, correct. Well it's all so dxxm long ago ... :}

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to initialize an array is with curly-brackets, not square brackets:

```
static struct alarm hi_aud = {
    {108, 27, 108, 20, 108, 12, 108, 5},              /* Initialize "pattern") */
    sizeof(hi_aud.pattern) / sizeof(*hi_aud.pattern), /* Initialize "size"     */
```

---

Assuming you already declared `struct alarm` properly (and you didn't quite get it, because you missed the second part of the typedef):

Your code is:

```
static       - This variable will have file-local scope.
struct alarm - The type of the variable.
hi_aud       - The name of the variable
{...}        - The structure initializers
```

You should also have an `=` between your variable at the structure initializers.

---

Addendum:

As others have pointed out, your code is a mess.

- You did not complete a typedef.
- You seem to be using variable length arrays in a language which does not support them
- Your VLAs are in the middle of a structure which has a comment that says the structure may "explode".
- In initializing structures, you're missing an `=` sign
- You are not initializing arrays properly.
- Your array sizes are all different.
- You have trailing commas and misplaced semi colons, etc, etc.

In general, Write a TINY amount of code first, compile it, debug it.
Then add on a little bit more, compile it and debug it.
Repeat.

Do NOT write several pages of junk, then look on in wonder as it doesn't work.

---

Towards that end, lets fix your first typedef:

Typedef works with 2-elements, The **TYPE**, and the new **NAME** for the type:

```
typedef {existing element} {new name};
```

You only put in the first half.

You want:

```
typedef struct alarm {  /* All the structure elements */ } alarm_t;
```

This makes a new type `alarm_t`.

After that, you tried to make the first element of the structure an array of undefined size.  C allows flexible array members, but ONLY as the very last element of a struct, and those are tricky to use.   So I'm going to make your array a fixed size:

```
typedef struct alarm {
    const uint_fast32_t pattern[10];  /* Fixed Size */
    const uint_fast8_t size;
    void (*toggle)(void);
    void (*off)(void);
    bool on;
    bool init;
    uint_fast8_t pos;
    uint_fast16_t start;
    uint_fast8_t overflows;
} alarm_t;
```

Comment: In any case, if you're going to close the question as a dupe, then it is inappropriate to also write an answer.

Comment: Wow, this is a really thorough and in-depth guide. I ended up putting the VLAs in program memory outside of the struct and using a pointer to the array inside the struct.

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for typedef for a struct is:

```
struct <optional struct name> {
    struct fields...
} <typedef name>;
```

You haven't supplied any typedef name.